# How to use hasMany association with multiple lists and stores?

Tags: extjs4.2

I have a question as the topic suggests. In my web application i got 4 classes which are related to each other so a "class 1" object has many "class 2" objects inside, a "class 2" object has many "class 3" objects inside and so on. 
How to make Store for this type of Structure.

Comment: Could you put in a sample of your code?

Comment: Thanks for responding .
ok will try to explain the problem and put the code.